# Electrical wiring brown and black only

Tags: electrical, switch

I want to change the classical electrical switches in my newly purchased house to smart switches and I am very confused in regard with the electrical wiring carried out by the home developer. The smart switches are making references to red, white, black and yellow wires while the attached image indicates that 3 out of the 4 wires are black. Any suggestion how I can sort out these connections ?[image]

Comment: are those the only wires in the box?

Comment: What area is this house in, how old is the house? Also flagging for migration to DIY, the home improvement stack exchange.

Comment: Can you post a photo looking into the back of the box?

Comment: The "brown" is not a brown wire, it is a bare copper wire which has tarnished, and it is for ground.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if in your box you have also neutrals, if you have pigtailed (neutral), usually white, wire inside the box. In that case, you have a 'permanent' phase on the black wires (I'd bet the two wires going to single screw) and a 'switched' phase on the other black wire (that is the wire going to the lamp) and that in newer setups usually is red.

So you'll have all 3 wires needed: PE (bare copper), permanent phase (two wires that now goes on single screw), neutral (white pigtailed wires inside the box).

If you don't have other wires inside the box you should call an electrician to pull a new wire or just remain with current setup.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, determining the true "always hot" wire (or side of the switch) is easy if you have a test light. (with the switch in off position place one lead of the light against on side of the switch and the other on the copper (brown) wire, whichever terminal results in a light is the hot terminal.

This appears to be a situation where the terminal which has the two black wires attached is the Hot side, part of a hot loop or run in the house.  The other side of the switch (with single black wire) is likely running to your light or switched outlet.

The wiring convention is black for hot, white for neutral and red for other such as a common terminal on a two-way switch arrangement (two switches control one light or outlet).  In this case the side wth two wires is likely (1) hot wire coming in and then (1) hot wire"jumping" to the next outlet or junction box (distributing the hot loop).  The wire on the other terminal must by code be black because it is sometimes hot (when the switch is "on").

Hope that helps

Comment: While it is likely to work, I don't recommend using a "test light" as described. As described, you are using ground as a conductor. Technically that will work - and isn't a fire hazard when used for a few seconds as described - but is not the way ground is supposed to be used. If you have a GFCI breaker on the circuit (unlikely, unless the whole panel was upgraded with GFCI breakers at some point) then it will trip due to a ground fault. The better way to test is a non-contact tester like https://www.amazon.com/Voltage-Protection-Klein-Tools-NCVT-2/dp/B004FXJOQO/ref=sr_1_3